# Preg_replace YouTube video string to embed code in paragraph

Tags: php, youtube, preg-replace

I have this pattern for preg_replace.

```
#<a>(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*<\/a>#x
```

But I need change it, for this case.

```
<p>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5bgJSdH544(<br/>)</p>
```

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$string = '<p>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5bgJSdH544(<br/>)</p>';

if(preg_match('#<(?:a|p)>(?:href="https?://|http://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*<\/(?:a|p)>#x', $string)){ 
    echo 'Match found.';
}else{
    echo 'No match found.';
}
```

- Replaced the a in the opening and closing anchor tags with (?:a|p)
- Added an or condition to the second group: (?:href="https?://|http://)?
- The .* near the end of the expression already takes care of the added `(<br/>)` portion.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Could you help with case where string is only in paragraph? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer to show a working example of the reworked expression.